# Как создать свой собственный режим?

Tags: lisp, emacs

Что я хочу сделать: вводить свою команду с помощью M-x и чтоб включался особый режим где работали мои замапленные клавиши. Потом, с помощью своей команды я этот режим хочу отключить и вернуть всё на свои места? как примерно это можно сделать и что можно почитать?

Comment: Попробуйте просто пробедатся по готовым режимам (mode). C-h f fundamental или org-mode